# Super simple flash player for audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, audio

I'm looking for a super simple plugin or flash file for audio to fallback from HTML5 `<audio>` tag with.

I want to be able to connect this to my own element rather than have an existing interface/player.  Super leight weight with the only functionality being `stop()` and `play()`.  Or even easier a play that automatically calls stop first then replays.

Also would be nice to have a dynamic swf for fallback so I don't have to load multiple copies of it on the same page and can just load it once and feed in a file path for it to play.

A jQuery or JS plugin would be great or if anyone has a link to just a `swf` file that would be awesome and I can just create my own plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Flowplayer for quite a while now. Its API allows us to control the player easily through Javascript.

http://flowplayer.org/

If you're looking for something even simpler, take a look at Dewplayer. Never used it, but seems nice and simple enough.

http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer-en.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS), which I've helped develop.  It allows you to write a single code base that works anywhere, and gracefully uses Web Audio, html audio tags, or flash as appropriate.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Having a lot of issues with this plugin after trying it.  In IE some files don't load and it's random on every refresh.  Also some inconsistencies in FF.  The events also don't seem to fire.  And it's like 10 files that need to be included, bit messy.

Comment: IE has a limit on the number of html audio tags that can be loaded that is shared across all tabs. In our tests this is always above 30, so we've pegged 30 as a safe lower limit. The just released Firefox 25 newly supports web audio, which has known issues that we are addressing (see details [here](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/soundjs/1208-firefox-25-web-audio-support)). It may be worth your time to check out the [Test Suite Demo](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos/testSuite) to play around with the soundjs features and fallbacks.